# C# 2015, cannot open for writing when already built

Tags: c#

I use a code library in all my projects. Regularly I work on several projects at the same time. If one of my projects is running in debug mode, I can't run another project in debug mode, because the dll of the code library can't be opened for writing.

I agree this makes sense, but when I used C# 2008 Express, there was no problem in this scenario.

Any thoughts, or should I live with this?

As reply to the question by WiiMaxx: I include the project of the code library, as I'm making frequent changes to the library. Perhaps I should organise these changes and just include the DLL.

==============================================================
Edit:

I haven't been clear in my original question, so second try:

I use a common code library, containing standard forms, and things like connection to the (mySQL) database. 
I include the project of the code library in all of my solutions, and make a reference from the main project to the code library if necessary. 
This way I can make frequent changes to the code library, every time I create something in a solution that can be used again I copy it to my code library, to it is available in other solutions as well.

The weird thing is it is only with my own code library that I expierience this problem, other projects I include in the solution (and reference them), don't suffer from this effect.

Comment: A better word for function library is `Code Library`, or even better, `DLL`.
(A DLL contains more than just functions.)

Comment: have you just added the reference to your dll or did you include the Project of your dll?

Comment: i add multiple projects(like libraries) in one solution. then reference them in running project. so i can edit all of the projects at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you are referencing a dll that is external to your solution (eg in a packages or references folder). If it was a dll that is generated from a project in your solution i would expect that to be copied into the bin directory of the project you are running so you wouldn't get this issue.

Have you got copy local turned on on the reference?  that might solve your problem.

Nuget is a solution to a similar kind of problem. It sprobalby worth taking a look especially if you ever change the dll you are talking about.

Comment: The key in your answer is "If it was a DLL that is generated from a project in your solution, to be copied into the bin directory of the project you are running". The DLL is created in the bin directory of the code library project. I try to find a setting for the behaviour you describe!

Comment: did you add a project reference or did you reference the dll directly?